# Convert linked html files into a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, conversion, html

I would like to convert [an online book (](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/index.html)linked html files) into a pdf file.

I tried the two-step way in http://kmkeen.com/mirror/2009-02-05-14-00-00.html

1. First, download the html files by

   ```
   wget -nd -mk http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/
   ```

   But it has downloaded a lot of nonrelated files. So I have to remove
   the unrelated files.
2. Then, I try to convert the downloaded html book into a pdf file:

   ```
   htmldoc --webpage -f gdb.pdf html/index.html html/*.html
   ```

   but the order of pages in the pdf file isn't correct.

I wonder what good way to download and convert an online book (linked html files) into a pdf file?

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the instructions you linked:

> The default glob expansion puts the pages in alphabetical order.

The index page links to nine different documents, whose names aren't in alphabetical order. When you say `htmldoc ... *.html`, the tools sees them in that order and puts the pages into the document alphabetically. You need to list the files on the command line in the order you want `htmldoc` to process them.

In this specific case you can produce an ordered list of filenames as they're linked in the index with:

```
awk '/http:|\.\./ {next}; /<a href.*\.html/ { gsub(/.*href="/, "") ; gsub(".html.*", ".html") ; print }' index.html | uniq
```

so

```
htmldoc --webpage -f gdb.pdf index.html $(awk '/http:|\.\./ {next}; /<a href.*\.html/ { gsub(/.*href="/, "") ; gsub(".html.*", ".html") ; print }' index.html | uniq)
```

will have the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks. about 1, `wget -nd -mk http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/` also downloads files under `http://www.unknownroad.com`. How could I download the files under `http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/` only?

Comment: See wget's `--domains` and `--no-parent` options.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Can htmldoc create multilevel bookmarks in the resulting pdf file? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153433/can-htmldoc-create-multi-level-pdf-bookmarks