# Can htmldoc create multi-level pdf bookmarks?

Tags: pdf, conversion, html

I downloaded an online html book (http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~franco/OpSys-304-427/lecture-notes/lecture-notes.html), by the following command

```
wget -r -np  -nH --cut-dirs=3 -p -k http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~franco/OpSys-304-427/lecture-notes/lecture-notes.html
```

Then I tried to convert it to pdf using htmldoc.  My command is:

```
htmldoc --webpage -f 1.pdf lecture-notes.html node1.html node2.html ... node69.html
```

The resulting PDF file has bookmarks for its table of content shown in `lecture-notes.html`, but the bookmarks are just one-level. The table of content shown in `lecture-notes.html` is multilevel however,  indicated in HTML source code by `<UL>` and `</UL>` pairs.

Another example is http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/, which uses a different way to represent multi-level table of content in its HTML source code.

Can `htmldoc` create multilevel bookmarks for table of content?

Comment: You could also try pandoc.

Comment: @Jan: Thanks. Do you know how to do what I asked in pandoc? (either CLI or GUI is fine, although CLI is preferred)

Comment: How did you download the lecture notes? Do you now have a single file or multiple ones?

Comment: @Jan Multiple html files. The command I used for downloading them is `wget -r -np  -nH --cut-dirs=3 -p -k http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~franco/OpSys-304-427/lecture-notes/lecture-notes.html`