# How to use wget to download an online eBook

Tags: wget, conversion, html, ebooks

sorry for my English....

I to try to Download [this](https://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/linag3ger/) Ebook, I tried different methods with **Wget**, with

```
wget --domains --no-parent https://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/linag3ger
```

and

```
wget --domains --no-parent https://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/linag3ger/418_LinuxIVZ.html
```

Only Download the Links for the Site.

With,

```
wget -r https://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/linag3ger/418_LinuxIVZ.html
```

so, with recursive, Download all Webpage....more as 1GB....

I'll Download it, and late to convert it to PDF, as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151096) to say.

Can please someone help me, Thanks!

Comment: I misread the title as "How to download wget with an ebook"

Comment: Now to change the title **How to download with Wget an eBook**, also when the Preposition **with** is before the name **wget**, I think is cleary what to say...

Comment: Because of some people, not ready gut the title... I to come **-2** ....

Comment: @ annahri, How **Konfuzius** to say, **To make a mistake and not to correct it - that is really to make a mistake**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like all you have to do is this:

```
wget -np -r -l 2 'https://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/linag3ger/'
```

This downloads 49 files, 3.7MB in total.

Basically you need `-r` to tell wget to download the link recursively. Then `-l 2` to tell wget to not go deeper than 2 levels.

Comment: Thanks!, I have before to try with `-r` but without to tell wget, the deeper... I wish you a nice Day!

Comment: Info for other people, what **man wget** to say about `-np`:  **Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.**

Comment: Can Please someone tell me because to come **-1** ?, I think people which give **-1** , MUSS to say because give it!

Comment: **-1** more... people as you give me to fear only to think when a Day you are to come more power....

Comment: Some people might think it’s not ok to download the book when the website doesn’t provide a download option. That’s my guess. But I think it’s totally ok to download.

Comment: I to say it because of every time that I`ll ask a question, to come to a warning that to say that I have many **-1**..., too I think it is people give **-1** without reliable reason...

Comment: ...Also this Book it is possible download...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Network_Administrator%27s_Guide

Answer (score 0):

You will have to tell `wget` a criterion what to download (anything below that folder?) and what not (all the rest of the Wiley website).

If you have a GUI available, a tool like "HTTrack Website Copier" may simplify that task.

Comment: **anything below that folder?**, how to understand, the folder is **linag3ger**... with **https://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/** to come  a empty Page....

Comment: By and large, the crawled URLs must be limited to start with `https://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/linag3ger/`.